# Docusign "WITNESS_FOR_SIGNER_ID_INVALID"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have two recipients in my template that need to be witnessed. My requirement is to, keep the second recipient optional. That means I want to specify one or two recipients.
I could create the envelope without the optional recipient, if the recipients don't need to be witnessed. As soon as I change the template so that they require a witness, I receive this error unless both are specified,

> One or more errors occurred. (Error calling CreateEnvelope:
> {"errorCode":"WITNESS_FOR_SIGNER_ID_INVALID","message":"The witness
> host signer Id is not valid. Witness recipient id = 4"})

I'm using `CompositeTemplates` to create the template.

```
EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition {
   CompositeTemplates = compositeTemplates, 
   Status = "created"
};

var apiClient1 = new ApiClient(acct.BaseUri + "/restapi");
apiClient1.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.access_token);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient1);
EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(acct.AccountId, env, new EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeOptions { mergeRolesOnDraft= "true"});
```

So how can I create envelope with optional recipients that need to be witnessed?

Comment: are you sure the witness you set in the template is optional?

Comment: @InbarGazit No. That's not optional. But I want to keep it as optional

Comment: You cannot do it this way. What you can do, is not have the witness in your template, and add it as an extra recipient in your code when you want to. But if a recipient is not optional on a template - it must be added to any envelope created from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the template includes a recipient that is not optional, then when you create an envelope from this template - **you must include** that recipient.

To support your scenario, remove the witness recipient from the template. You can then use your code to add the witness when you want it